# Why is the SceneView not rendering correct

Tags: typescript, arcgis-js-api

I am getting up to speed on the ArcGIS JS Api Version 4.x and deemed it a good exercise on Typescript and Widget architecture to implement a widget, that displays a `SceneView` on top of the current `MapView`.

```
/// <amd-dependency path="esri/core/tsSupport/declareExtendsHelper" name="__extends" />
/// <amd-dependency path="esri/core/tsSupport/decorateHelper" name="__decorate" />

import EsriMap from 'esri/Map';
import SceneView = require("esri/views/SceneView");

import { aliasOf, declared, property, subclass } from "esri/core/accessorSupport/decorators";

// building Widgets
import Widget = require("esri/widgets/Widget");
import { accessibleHandler, renderable, cssTransition, tsx } from "esri/widgets/support/widget";


// CSS class lookup object
const CSS = {
    base: "app-sceneView",
    iconClass: "esri-icon-layer-list"
};

@subclass("Widgets.SceneViewWidget")
export default class SceneViewWidget extends declared(Widget) {

    constructor(params?: any) {
        super();
    }

    //icon class for the expand widget(!)
    @property()
    iconClass = CSS.iconClass;

    map: EsriMap = null;

    _bindView() {
        const view = new SceneView({
            map: this.map,
            container: "sceneView-container"
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="sceneView-container" class={CSS.base} afterCreate={this._bindView}></div>
    }
}
```

The container for the widget is rendering fine at the desired position, and controls, such as the zoom buttons are also there, but the map is not rendered, when called like this:

```
const map = new EsriMap({
    basemap: "streets",
    ground: "hybrid"
});
const mapView = new MapView({
    map: map,
    container: "mapView",
    center: [-118.244, 34.052],
    zoom: 12,
    ui: {
        components: ["zoom", "compass"]
    }
});

const sceneView = new SceneViewWidget({
    map: map
});

mapView.ui.add(sceneView, "top-right");
```

[image]

As you can see. The boundary for the div is there, controls are rendered and the attribution is there too. Only the SceneView itself is missing. Why is that?

Comment: is it a css problem?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Unlikely. The controls are greyed out, while to MapView controls outside the image have black-ish lines. I'd tend to a lifecycle issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the [`SceneView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html) is not rendering in the above TypeScript code is that `this.map` in `_bindView()` is null, because of `this` being function- and not object scoped.

```
_bindView() {
  new SceneView({
    map: this.map,
    container: "sceneView-container"
  });
}
```

That can be fixed by passing a correctly scoped `_bindView()` function in `render()`:

```
render() {
  return <div afterCreate={this._bindView.bind(this)} id="sceneView-container" class={CSS.base}></div>;
}
```

or

```
render() {
  return <div afterCreate={() => this._bindView()} id="sceneView-container" class={CSS.base}></div>;
}
```

See the following CodePen for a working demo (plain JavaScript):
https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/1a801eca6a01ca9bf7625f89f906b6e7

---

Besides I would also recommend changing the following in the code above:

- Wrap the [SceneView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html) container `sceneView-container` in an additional `<div>` to avoid the Widget and SceneView sharing the same element:

```
<div><div id="sceneView-container" class={CSS.base} afterCreate={this._bindView.bind(this)}></div></div>
```

- Pass a valid value for [`Map.ground`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#ground), e.g.

```
const map = new EsriMap({
  basemap: "streets",
  ground: "world-elevation"
});
```

- Provide separate [Map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html) instances to [MapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) and [SceneView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html), avoiding the two views interfering with each other. Simply create a new one using `new EsriMap(...)`.

---

Comment: Adding a sceneview to a plain map works flawlessly. I specifically try to wire one up inside the widget life cycle, and that is where it fails

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the sceneViewer-container element in an additional <div> in your render() function? e.g. <div class={CSS.base} afterCreate={this._bindView}><div id="sceneView-container"></div></div>

Comment: I did and it did not have any visual effect.

Comment: So simple, yet utterly amazing. You deserve a beer.